# Ubuntu Software Centre is very slow

Tags: 13.04

Ubuntu Software Center is very slow, I would prefer the terminal to install or remove app because it is slow. Do you all experience the same ?. For example if you click on Install or Remove on the 2nd application, the download bar will not show any progress. Eventually it gets downloaded but the GUI doesn't show it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

For a graphical package manager, you can try **Synaptic Package Manager**. It's much faster than USC. Write this in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Another suggestion: apt is great and extremely fast, just give a try to **apt-fast**.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install apt-fast`

You will have a much faster download experience with **apt-fast**.
More here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/speed-up-apt-get-downloads-with-apt.html